# Impdp over DB_LINK failing with ORA-31631

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, impdp

I am getting below error message while trying to execute impdp between our SIT and UAT environments:

**ORA-31631: privileges are required**

**ORA-39149: cannot link privileged user to non-privileged user**

The Roles for the source database are :

EXP_FULL_DATABASE

IMP_FULL_DATABASE

RUBY_FULL_ROLE

SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE

The roles for the target Database are:

CONNECT

EXP_FULL_DATABASE

IMP_FULL_DATABASE

RESOURCE

SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE

As we can see, both the source and target schemas have **IMP_FULL_DATABASE** and **EXP_FULL_DATABASE** roles.

Can someone please help me out with this.

Thanks for Help

Vishad

Comment: Can you check if EXP_FULL_DATABASE role is granted to the user which db link connects as?

Comment: @Raj: Yes, have verrified that the EXP_FULL_DATABASE is available to that user.